# How slicing and ellipsis works in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, slice, ellipsis

I have been reading a very old documentation of **Numpy** and found out a weird notation which eludes my understanding. The documentation says `a[i:...]` is a shortcut for `a[i,:,:,:]`.

The documentation being old is very vague and I would welcome any comments.

Thanks,
Prerit

Comment: Your question is undoubtedly more vague than the documentation.I'd look at the [actual documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html) though.

Comment: wait, what? I was looking at wrong documentation? LOL

Comment: `a[,:,:,]` is a syntax error

Comment: Can you explain me how this indexing/splicing is working, I am not getting a hold of the concept.

Comment: Why don't you create an array for yourself and test what it does?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three full stops `...` (and not `…` (U+2026)), refers to the [Ellipsis](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#the-ellipsis-object) singleton object. It has no built-in special operations but is often used in slicing expressions.

No built-in classes utilise the Ellipsis object however NumPy uses `...` as a shortcut when slicing arrays, for example, where `x` is a 4D array: `x[i, ...]` is equivalant to `x[i, :, :, :]`.

[NumPy - Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Answer (score 2):

`arr[:,:,1]` is fancy indexing used by numpy that selects the first element of the last column in `arr`. Fancy indexing can only be used in numpy arrays and not in python's traditional lists.
Also, like its pointed out in the comments, `a[,:,:,]` is a syntax error.

It is helpful because you can select columns easily

Comment: Thanks John! I edited my question, I think I shouldn't have given the example of a[,:,:,] which is clearly wrong, I gave it naively. But my main question is how does ellipses work during indexing. Thanks for answering it John, I appreciate it, Everyone else is focused on pointing my error rather than answering my question.